# Adding a colon (:) to an unsigned char in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, char, arduino, const-char

I am writing an Arduino library for simple data transfers between the Arduino and a computer using a serial feed. I have created the library, etc. However, I am having issues with taking a char array, and adding a colon (':') to it. That is,

```
//Sends data via println()
void simpleTransfer::sendData(char *name, char *data){
    char *str = name + ": " + data + ",";
    _serial->println(str); //Sends in form 'name: data,'
}
```

This should take the name of a variable that I want to send, add a colon and a space, and the data I want to send and finally a comma. However, I instead get error messages:

> invalid operands of types 'char*' and 'const char [3]' to binary 'operator+'

What is the reason?

Comment: You're looking for *string concatenation*.  Adding two pointers doesn't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/):

```
char str[64];  // Or whatever length you need to fit the resulting string
sprintf(str, "%s:%s,", name, data);
```

Or [strcpy/strcat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/):

```
char str[64];
strcpy(str, name);
strcat(str, ":");
strcat(str, data);
strcat(str, ",");
```

Or just use C++'s [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+/).

Comment: Same comment as above: `std::string` is not appropriate for Arduino. the `sprintf` method is better, but requires pulling in certain libraries which significantly increase code size, also not desirable on Arduino

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: use `std::string` to create the concatenated string.

```
 std::string s = ((std::string(name) + ": ") + data) + ",";
_serial->println( s.c_str() );
```

Long answer: when concatenating C-style strings, you need a destination buffer that's large enough to hold the result. If you know the maximum size that the result can ever get to, you can declare a local array of that size, and use `sprintf` as the other answers explains.

Or, if you don't know the size in advance, you can use a combination of `strlen` and `new[]` to allocate a dynamically size buffer, do the printing, then `delete[]` the buffer. But don't do this! Use a string class instead, either `std::string`, or as Drew Dormann mentions in the comments below, an Arduino specific `String` class.

Comment: ... From what I can tell, Arduino's C++ implementation doesn't have header `<string>`, but does provide a type `String` that would support the syntax you've written.  Correct me if I'm wrong, anyone.  :)

Comment: @DrewDormann: Oh, I wasn't aware Arduino had that!  http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject

Comment: You really don't want to use standard C++ libraries on an Arduino: it's a low resource platform.  For this reason it has its own string implementation.